# How does one format YYYYMM as javascript date?

Tags: javascript

I am working with database data that is in YYYYMM format. I am hoping to present it in javascript for analysis. I have looked through the documentation for Intl.DateTimeFormat and was trying it out. However, it does not seem to interpret it correctly.

An example date is `201701` for Jan. of 2017.

```
console.log('201701')
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format('201701'));  // Will give 12/31/1969 oddly enough
```

How do I format dates with YYYYMM format? I have not seen any answers to this question online or on SO and this seems to be a pretty common date format from databases. I am using vanilla Javascript and do not want to use moment.js as it is over kill for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could help:

```
let dateStr = '201701'
let year = dateStr.substring(0,4)
let month = parseInt( dateStr.substring(4,6) ) - 1

console.log(new Date(year, month))
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it gives me the right output everytime. Other answers kept the month without the minus one which gives me the month before. What I realized from this answer is what I think I might have seen elsewhere on SO: it seems months are 0 based so 01 -> 1 -> feburary where as 0 is January, which is very confusing. My advice for people working with month dates is that if they are getting the next month they need to see if 0 is being interpreted as January

Answer (score 2):

```
dateStr = '201701'

date = new Date(dateStr.slice(0, 4) + '-' + dateStr.slice(4)) // Sun Jan 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

Comment: Is something like this implementation dependent? On my system, firefox, I get December 31st. In particular, I get `Date Sat Dec 31 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Comment: btw, I forgot `let` or `const` because I am doing lots of Coffeescript these days

Comment: Thats fine. I getcha!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
const year = "201701".slice(0, 4)
const month = "201701".slice(4, 6)    
const dateObject = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1)
console.log(dateObject)
```

Comment: Running this code snippet for me gives Dec31st of 2016 oldly enough. Is that based on my browser?

Comment: yes since it runs on your browser depends on your computer locale i see "2017-01-31T21:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trivial date parser.

Just find the start/end indices of a particular token. It it extensible too. You could easily add support for time.

```js
const parseDate = (dateStr, format) => {
  const FMT_YEAR  = 'Y',
        FMT_MONTH = 'M',
        FMT_DATE  = 'D'
  
  const token = (str, startIndex, endIndex) => startIndex !== endIndex ?
    parseInt(str.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1), 10) : 0
  
  let yearStartIndex  = format.indexOf(FMT_YEAR),
      yearEndIndex    = format.lastIndexOf(FMT_YEAR),
      monthStartIndex = format.indexOf(FMT_MONTH),
      monthEndIndex   = format.lastIndexOf(FMT_MONTH),
      dateStartIndex  = format.indexOf(FMT_DATE),
      dateEndIndex    = format.lastIndexOf(FMT_DATE)
      
  let year  = token(dateStr, yearStartIndex, yearEndIndex),
      month = token(dateStr, monthStartIndex, monthEndIndex) - 1,
      date  = token(dateStr, dateStartIndex, dateEndIndex) || 1
      
  return new Date(year, month, date)
}

console.log(parseDate('201701', 'YYYYMM').toString())
```

Here is a more concise version.

```js
const parseDate = (dateStr, format) => {
  const extract = (dateStr, format, token) =>
    ((startIndex, endIndex) => startIndex !== endIndex ?
        parseInt(dateStr.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1), 10) : 0
    )(format.indexOf(token), format.lastIndexOf(token))

  return new Date(
    extract(dateStr, format, 'Y'),
    extract(dateStr, format, 'M') - 1,
    extract(dateStr, format, 'D') || 1
  )
}

console.log(parseDate('201701', 'YYYYMM').toString())
```